# Getting form fields to clear when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/oh9Ltpxm/

I am trying to get the form when a user fills out the info and decides to remove the person by clicking on the remove radio button I want it to clear all the data. I tried to create some java to clear the input based on name="" but I cant seem to get it working. what am I doing wrong? forgot to add that this form has multiple remove buttons and multiple name, gen, ssn, ddn, dob fields. I only want it to remove its respected field

html

```
 add a person<br/>
 <input type="radio" id="bn" name="age2" value="Yes" class="aboveage2" onclick="ClearFields();"/> Remove
 <input type="radio" id="bn" name="age2" value="No" class="aboveage2" /> Yes
 <br/>
 <div id="righttxt">
 <input type="text" name="name" class="box" max=40 placeholder=""/><br/>
 <input type="date" name="dob" class="box" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" maxlength="10" min="1" max="10"  onKeyPress="return numbersonly(this, event)"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="ddn" class="box" placeholder=""/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="ssn" max=11 class="box" placeholder="" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(this, event)"/><br/>
 <input id="bn" name="gen" type="radio" value="Male">Male
 <input id="bn" name="gen" type="radio" value="Female">Female
 </div><!--righttext-->
```

javascript

```
function ClearFields() {
  document.getElementByname "name".value = "";
  document.getElementByname "bod".value = "";
  document.getElementByname "ddn".value = "";
  document.getElementByname "ssn".value = "";
  document.getElementByname "gen".value = "";  
}
```

Comment: Like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/oh9Ltpxm/1/**

Comment: Although it's been said many times, many ways, "JavaScript does not equal Java!" </Nat King Cole>

Comment: forgot to add that this form has multiple remove buttons and multiple name, gen, ssn, ddn, dob fields. I only want it to remove its respected field.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect for document.getElementByname .  The correct function name is `getElementsByName`.  It also returns a nodelist so your code should more appropriately be:

```
function ClearFields() {
  document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName("bod")[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName("ddn")[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName("ssn")[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName("gen")[0].value = "";   
}
```

You should only have one element with the ID of `bn`.

I would also move away from using `onclick`, etc in your HTML and instead use a more modern technique:

```
document.getElementById('bn').addEventListener('click', ClearFields , false);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: it's getElementsByName not getElementByName btw.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is way off here, try this:

```
function clearFields() {
  document.getElementsByName("name").value = "";
  document.getElementsByName("bod").value = "";
  document.getElementsByName("ddn").value = "";
  document.getElementsByName("ssn").value = "";
  document.getElementsByName("gen").value = "";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
function clearFields(name, val) {
  document.getElementByName(name)[0].value = val;
}
clearFields("name", "");
clearFields("bod", "");
clearFields("ddn", "");
clearFields("ssn", "");
clearFields("gen", "");
```

Comment: Please add some description to why this is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others the correct method is `document.getElementsByName()`.  However, this will return all the fields with a given name.

As OP added in comments

> forgot to add that this form has multiple remove buttons and multiple name, gen, ssn, ddn, dob fields. I only want it to remove its respected field.

Given that field names are repeated elsewhere, it would not be possible to directly select elements, as it will reset unrelated.

I would propose that you place all these fields within a container, and use jQuery to reset the various input within.

try something like

```
<h3>add a person</h3>
<fieldset style="border:none;">
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="bn" name="age2" value="Yes" class="aboveage2" onclick="ClearFields($(this));"/> 
    <label>Remove</label>
    <input type="radio" id="bn" name="age2" value="No" class="aboveage2" />
    <label>Yes</label>
</div>

<div id="righttxt">
    <div><input type="text" name="name" class="box" max=40 placeholder=""/></div>
    <div><input type="date" name="dob" class="box" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" maxlength="10" min="1" max="10"  onKeyPress="return numbersonly(this, event)"/></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="ddn" class="box" placeholder=""/></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="ssn" max=11 class="box" placeholder="" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(this, event)"/></div>

    <div>
        <input id="bn" name="gen" type="radio" value="Male"/>
        <label>Male</label>
        <input id="bn" name="gen" type="radio" value="Female"/>
        <label>Female</label>
    </div>
</div><!--righttext-->
</fieldset>
```

and the javascript can be

```
function ClearFields(ctrl) {
    var fieldset = ctrl.closest('fieldset');
    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[type="text"]').val("");
}
```

This will reset all radio and text input fields in the callee's parent fieldset.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/oh9Ltpxm/8/